# Sorting Map by Value, clarification needed

Tags: java, comparator

This has been asked several times, i know, but help me understand something.

You have a map you need sorted by Value

```
    Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    m.put("a", 1);
    m.put("b", 13);
    m.put("c", 22);
    m.put("d", 2);
```

You call a method to make it happen

```
public static List<String> sortByValue(final Map<String, Integer> unsortedMap) {

    List<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
    sortedKeys.addAll(unsortedMap.keySet());

    Collections.sort(sortedKeys, new MapComparator(unsortedMap));

    return sortedKeys;
}
```

You have a comparator class

```
public MapComparator(Map<String, Integer> m) {
    this.m = m;
}

@Override
public int compare(String a, String b) {

    int x = m.get(a);
    int y = m.get(b);

    if (x > y)
        return x;
    if (y > x)
        return y;

    return 0;

}
```

This code, obviously is flawed. Please help me understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if (x > y)
    return x;
  if (y > x)
    return y;

  return 0;
```

You should be returning `1` if `x > y` and `-1` if `y > x`.  The `Comparator` contract specifies that you return a negative number if the first value is less than the second, a positive number if the first is greater than the second, and zero if they're equal.

(Mind you, as it stands, this `Comparator` implementation will break in very confusing ways if you ever happen to use values that aren't in the original map.)

Better yet, just return `Integer.compare(x, y)`, which does all that for you.  (Only in Java 7, though.)

Comment: Louis, this does not work unfortunately. Results still appear unsorted

Comment: Using values that aren't in the original map will result in a `NullPointerException` when unboxing `(Integer) null`, not because of any problems with your edit.

Comment: @JAM, can you post your updated code?  This looks like it ought to work.

Comment: Louis, thank you for your help. It was a silly typo elsewhere that led me to believe something was wrong. Again, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public int compare(String a, String b) {

    Integer x = m.get(a);
    Integer y = m.get(b);

    return x.compareTo(y);
}
```

Since you have Integer objects as values, you can use the implicit method to compare the objects and return 1, 0 or -1.

Answer (score 0):

Comparators don't return the greater or lesser value.  They return a negative value to indicate less-than or a positive value to indicate greater than.

```
if (x > y)
    return x;
if (y > x)
    return y;

return 0;
```

should probably be

```
if (x > y)
    return -1;
if (y > x)
    return 1;

return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator only ever indicates that the values are equal or that the left is greater than the right.

Consider the case where `x` is 1 and `y` is 2. Your comparator will return 2—a positive number—when it should have returned a negative number.

I recommend that you study [the `Comparator` interface documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) again to see which part of the contract you're missing out on here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> sortByValue(final Map<String, Integer> unsortedMap) {
    List<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
    sortedKeys.addAll(unsortedMap.keySet());

    Collections.sort(sortedKeys, new Comparator<String>(){
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return unsortedMap.get(s1).compareTo(unsortedMap.get(s2));
        }});
    return sortedKeys;
}
```